# How to keep first weight of each subject id in SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to retain the data of the first weight given by each SUBJID. How do I do that?
sample data

```
DATA Have;
Input SUBJID WEIGHT;
01 88
01 86
01 86
02 .
02 101
02 100
;
run;
```

expected data:

```
SUBJID WEIGHT
01 88
02 101
```

Comment: Does not look you need to retain anything since you are only writing one observation with the first weight.

Answer (score 0):

Use FIRST. in SAS.

```
data want;
set have;
where not missing weight;
by subjid;
if first.subjid;
run;
```

Comment: that does not keep the first given weight on my actual data.

Comment: Filter out the missing values.

Comment: I would more the WHERE statement before the IF statement to make it clearer to the humans reading the code what is intended.